# seek() a file within a zip file in Python without passing it to memory

Tags: python, zip, seek, python-zipfile

is there anyway to make a file inside a zip file seekable in Python without reading it to memory?

I tried the obvious procedure but I get an error since the file is not seekable:

```
In [74]: inputZipFile = zipfile.ZipFile("linear_g_LAN2A_F_3keV_1MeV_30_small.zip", 'r')

In [76]: inputCSVFile = inputZipFile.open(inputZipFile.namelist()[0], 'r')   

In [77]: inputCSVFile
Out[77]: <zipfile.ZipExtFile at 0x102f5fad0>

In [78]: inputCSVFile.se
inputCSVFile.seek      inputCSVFile.seekable  

In [78]: inputCSVFile.seek(0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-f1f9795b3d55> in <module>()
----> 1 inputCSVFile.seek(0)

UnsupportedOperation: seek
```

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to do so for all zip files. DEFLATE is a stream compression algorithm, which means that there is no way to decompress arbitrary parts of the file without having decompressed everything before it. It *could* possibly be implemented for files that have been stored, but then you get in the unfavorable position where some entries are seekable and others aren't.

Comment: I see, thank you. But from what I'm searching, it's possible with tar files, correct?

Comment: Only if the tar file is uncompressed. As soon as you throw in gzip (DEFLATE) compression, you get the same problem.

Comment: Although it happens on the fly, I can use a gzip compressed tar file and seek inside it, Python seems to either be decompressing it in memory or somewhere in a tmp disk and the process takes  lot of time compared to an uncompressed file - about 1min vs 4 seconds to the example I'm trying. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

ZipExtFile is now seekable :

https://bugs.python.org/issue22908
https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/066df4fd454d6ff9be66e80b2a65995b10af174f